# Only one of my objects is displaying as black

Tags: 3d-view

At some point, the object that I was modeling became black.

Note that if I add another object here it will display with correct shading in the viewport. I have tried switching renderers, which did not change this result.

[image]

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apjdx7OGjfBIgrdsRFfAS-TVT8OZqQ?e=PXbRI9 this is the actuall link, it didn't seem to work on the original message

Comment: Apply the scale.

Comment: What do you mean by scale?

Comment: (1) Select the model. (2) Press Ctrl+A  (the **Apply** menu opens up) > choose *Scale*.

Comment: Could you explain what this means? It worked